# Import file into Oracle by using SQLLoader from VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, oracle11g, sql-loader

I'd like to be able to import data into Oracle by using SQLLoader (it's MUCH faster than using any other import option) from MS Access VBA.

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: SQL Loader is a loading utility, using that you can load your data files into Oracle tables with the help of Control file. How is your file from MS Access VBA looks like? Please give some sample data

Comment: It will always be different files and they will be text files. I guess I'm looking for a way to start the .ctl file from vba somehow. I have a few databases that I use as automation tools for recurring reports. Right now I export the data into oracle by using docmd.transferdatabase and for a file with a few million records it takes hours, 6-7 hours and maybe more. Using SQL loader it'd take minutes. Trying to speed things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not my solution, someone i work with solved this.

create a batch file (.bat) with the following command line

sqlldr username/password@oracleserver control=yourcontrolfile.CTL

and then run that from VBA